# django rest api save two django models at a time through a single rest api call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building an django rest api for saving/managing customer data for my project. I have two models. Customer for storing basic customer 
details and CustomerDetails for storing a bunch of customer details. I want to write a single api to create/update data for both the models.

How can I do this?

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    """some more fields to go"""


# Create your models here.
class CustomerDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='customer_details',
                             default=0)

    spouse_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    """many more fields to go"""
```

views.py

```
import pprint
from .models import Customer, CustomerDetails

from oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets

from .serializers import CustomerSerializer, CustomerDetailsSerializer
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import generics


admin.autodiscover()
# Create your views here.


# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)



class CustomerCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Customer
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Customer, CustomerDetails


class CustomerDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDetails
        fields = ('spouse_name',)

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer_details = CustomerDetailsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name', 'city',  'customer_details')
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'customer', views.CustomerViewSet, 'customers')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Have you tried  (APIView) insted of (generics.CreateAPIView)

Comment: Why you have not use same id(of customer model) as an foreign key in the the customer details model  so it will be efficient to refer the details  of customer and vice versa.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare, You mean like this?

`code
    class CustomerDetails(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, primary_key=True, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='customer_details',
                             default=0)

    spouse_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    """many more fields to go"""

`

Comment: @ArunSS No I mean, `code class CustomerDetails(models.Model): id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, primary_key=True, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer_details', default=0) spouse_name = models.CharField(max_length=256) interests = models.CharField(max_length=256)` """many more fields to go"""

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

```
Views.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

class CustomerProfile(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,) # File upload


    def post(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        data = request.data
        required_fields = ['name'] # required fields
        for field in required_fields:
            if field not in data.keys():
                return JSONResponse({'status':"error", "field_name":field, "message":"{0} field required" .format(field) })
            elif not data.get(field):
                return JSONResponse({'status':"error", "field_name":field, "message":"{0} field not empty" .format(field) })
        ## Validate 
        if pk:
            try:
                customer =  Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
            except Customer.DoesNotExist:
                pass # Return Error
        else:
            customer = Customer.objects.create(name=data['address'], city=data['city'], name=data['name'])
        cd = CustomerDetails.objects.create(customer=customer,....)
        return JSONResponse({'status':"success", "message":"Successfully updated profile",'full_name':artist.full_name, 'detial':detail_url})


urls.py

from apps.sample import views

url(r'^api/v1/customer/$', views.CustomerProfile.as_view()), ## For Save customer detail
url(r'^api/v1/customer/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CustomerProfile.as_view()), ## Edit Customer Detail
```

Comment: do you faced any issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you need `CustomerCreateAPIView` in this. `ModelViewSet` should be more than enough to perform all actions you need as long as you provide correct `customer_details` in your POST data.